# What does *%gs:0x10 do in assembler?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, reverse-engineering

What does following syntax do in GASM?

```
*%gs:0x10
```

I know that `call *%gs:0x10` call will `__kernel_vsyscall`, but i don't know what `*%register:value` do.

It's NASM equivalent looks like this: `call DWORD PTR gs:0x10`

Comment: in `call gs:0x10`, `gs:0x10` is a memory operand. `gs:0x10` is an address where the address to jump to is stored. This is a memory indirect call to an absolute address. _GS_ is the segment selector to do the memory reference through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [near absolute indirect (FF /2)](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_26.html) call to the target of the pointer in `gs:0x10`.
Note that `gs` is a selector register, not a general purpose register (see [Protected mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode)).
The instruction read the DWORD at the offset 0x10 (relative to segment `gs`) and makes a call to its value.
A direct call would have another effect entirely, possibly involving call gates.

---

`gs:0x10` is where [libc copies the address of `__kernel_vsyscall` during its initialization.](http://articles.manugarg.com/systemcallinlinux2_6.html)

The [AT&T syntax for the control transfer instructions](http://csiflabs.cs.ucdavis.edu/~ssdavis/50/att-syntax.htm) is

> Branch addressing using registers or memory operands must be prefixed by a '*'. To specify a "far" control tranfers, a 'l' must be prefixed, as in `ljmp`, `lcall`, etc. For example,
>
> ```
> GAS syntax          NASM syntax
> ==========          ===========
>
> jmp *100            jmp  near [100]
> call *100           call near [100]
> jmp *%eax           jmp  near eax
> jmp *%ecx           call near ecx
> jmp *(%eax)         jmp  near [eax]
> call *(%ebx)        call near [ebx]
> ljmp *100           jmp  far  [100]
> lcall *100          call far  [100]
> ljmp *(%eax)        jmp  far  [eax]
> lcal *(%ebx)        call far  [ebx]
> ret                 retn
> lret                retf
> lret $0x100         retf 0x100
> ```
>
> Segment-offset pointers are specified using the following format:
>
> ```
> jmp $segment, $offset
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I understand it know. Do you know how to ```call __kernel_vsyscall``` on x64 systems? What is equivalent of ```call *%gs:0x10``` in x64?

Comment: @user7428910 It's easier on x64, use the instruction `syscall`. A more informative guide is [here](https://filippo.io/linux-syscall-table/)

Comment: Yeah, I know it. syscall is normal way on x64, but I am interested in using __kernel_vsyscall, pure curiosity

Comment: @user7428910 The [vDSO mapped for x64 processes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html) does not export the `__kernel_vsyscall` symbol (look at the man page linked, there is a section specific per architecture). For 32-bit processes in compat-mode you can do as you would on x86.

Comment: Ok, I understand.

Comment: Do you know any other ways of executing syscall on x64 than `syscall` or `int 0x80`?

Comment: @user7428910 No, I'm not 100% sure but I don't think there are other ways. A syscall is controlled entry-point to the kernel from user space, there should be as few as possible ways to do that. Even `int 0x80` is just a compatibility layer over the only (and only one) needed `syscall`.